# How can I prevent OS X from resetting/disconnecting from wifi when left idle?

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, macos, sleep-wake

Doing work at home, I noticed that OS X would drop my wifi connection when I left my 2011 MacBook Pro and it went into idle mode (screen black, but still powered on).

When I moved the mouse or touched a key, OS X would "wake up" but not have a wifi connection. Then it would not connect to the wifi for a minute or two, before resuming normal connectivity.

This was new to me since I have had the machine for more than two years and had never experienced this, but recently updated OS X to Mavericks.

Comment: Same here after upgrading to Mavericks.

Comment: I still get this, but only on my old Mac 2011. My new MacBook Pro 2013 does not have this issue.

Comment: I get this when I am plugged in. I can't really use the laptop otherwise as the battery is nearing EOL and doesn't hold a charge very long. I am running Mavericks which I upgraded to from Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 3):

Goto System Preferences -> Energy Saver -> Check "Prevent computer from sleeping automatically when the display is off"

The options may be slightly different depending on what generation macbook you have, but this should help point you to the right place. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have this problem. My Macbook doesn't disconnect from the WLAN when entering the idle mode.
Does the Mac disconnects the connection while using the battery or even while using the power plug?
Did you upgraded from OSX < 10.9 to Mavericks or did you a clean install?

Answer (score 0):

On Ventura (macOS 13), this option has been moved to **System Settings** app,  `Displays > Advanced`, *Battery & Energy* section of that dialog. The setting text is also worded slightly differently:

> Prevent automatically sleeping on power adapter when the display is off

This may or may not be in addition to having to change **System Settings** app, `Battery`, *Energy Mode* section, setting "On power adapter" to "High Power".